# Pandas apply with multiple values does not work as expected

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to use a function that returns a tuple of values with the dataframe 'apply' fn - in order to populate several columns simultaneously. This simple repro shows it does not work as intended

This

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'a': 1}, {'a': 2}])
df[['x','y']] = df.apply(lambda r: (r['a']*10, r['a']*100), axis = 1 )
df
```

returns this - as desired

```
    a   x   y
0   1   10  20
1   2   100 200
```

While if I add a row

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'a': 1}, {'a': 2}, {'a': 3}])
df[['x','y']] = df.apply(lambda r: (r['a']*10, r['a']*100), axis = 1 )
df
```

it returns this error

```
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have almost got it right. You need to also add `.apply(pd.Series)`

```
df[['x','y']] = df.apply(lambda r: (r['a']*10, r['a']*100), axis = 1).apply(pd.Series)
```

This will give you:

```
   a   x    y
0  1  10  100
1  2  20  200
2  3  30  300
```

Answer (score -1):

I think assign would be better than apply

```
df2.assign(x=lambda x: x['a'] * 10, y=lambda x: x['a']*100)
```

Comment: well in this case sure, but this is just a repro. My actual use case is one where my function does expensive operations and returns several things out of it. If I could split in separate fns, I would just do
df['x'] = df.apply(...)
df['y'] = df.apply(...)

Comment: I suggested assign because `apply` on a data frame is a very inefficient process and should be avoided. The accepted answer has `apply` twice